# 3d plot of custom function with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d

I need to do a 3d plot with python. In the documentation there are not example that I can use.

Here my code:

```
f0=interp1d(t1,sig1,kind="cubic",bounds_error=False,fill_value=0)
g0=interp1d(t1,sig2,kind="cubic",bounds_error=False,fill_value=0)


""" Linear example """
A=5.
B=1.1
C=0
I=arange(t1.min(),t1.max(),1)

# g(t) and f1(t) are the periodical extension of f0 and g0
def s(t):
    return A+B*t+C*t*t


def g(t):
    M=g0.x.max()
    m=g0.x.min()

    t=t+m   
    t=t%M    

    return g0(t)

def f1(t):
    M=f0.x.max()
    m=g0.x.min()
    t=t+m   
    t=t%M    
    return f0(t)

# f(t) is the shifted version of f1(t).
def f(t):
    return f1(s(t))




# This is the cost function that we are trying to minimize
def cost(x):
    b=x[0]
    a=x[1]
    return norm(g(b*I+a)-f(I))



I2=array([s(t) for t in I]) # the interval defined by s(t)


aa=arange(A,A+10,0.5)
bb=arange(-1.5*B,1.5*B,0.1)
plot3d(aa,bb,cost) # This is what I would like<---------------
```

So that I can have a 3d plot of the cost function.

How can I do that?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with?

Comment: I do not understand how to get a 3d plot.  It should be easy plot(x,y,f(x,y))  I did  not find a solution

Comment: example [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo.py)

Comment: thanks but I think that my problem is that I am using sequence aa and bb of different length. Maybe I need to define aa and bb in order to have the same length